# How can I simulate a crash of OpenGL in GLKViewController to help track down a user's problem?

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I am using `GLKViewController` for iOS app. On some devices, there are problems (possibly with OpenGL), that I am unable to solve, because I dont see this problem on none of my devices or emulator.

Is there a way, how to "manually" force OpenGL (`GLKViewController`) to crash, but not to crash app? Or is there any other way, why `GLKViewController` instance can become null?

Comment: How do you know that there are problems in the first place?

Comment: From user reporting some problems with disappearing OpenGL view entirely.

Comment: Don't you get any crash-logs with the reports?

Comment: No, because app is still running. Only view with OpenGL is gone.

Comment: Can you narrow down whether this happens with specific devices or OS releases?

Comment: From what I know, it is device and iOS wide... there seems to be no common ground

Answer (score 1):

Sure, there are ways to cause [`GLKViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/glkit/glkviewcontroller) to crash, ranging from giving it a bad delegate, to swizzling one of its methods and dereferencing a null pointer in the implementation, et cetera.

But doing so is pointless. It wouldn't help you fix a crash that users were seeing unless you happened to randomly choose to recreate precisely that crash, which would be *very* unlikely. And it certainly won't help you fix a problem that users are reporting that isn't even a crash.

What you probably want to do instead is ship a build with improved error checking and logging around the operations you're doing with the view controller and OpenGL setup. Log what is going on, make sure you're checking any `NSError` objects that are filled out, et cetera. Hopefully with such a build (which you may be able to distribute specifically to the users experiencing the problems), you will be able to generate a log that can help lead you down the right path.

Comment: Or simply with a debug mode you can activate through console. You wouldn't have to distribute a special version that way